# Split string has symbols(many pipes) with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string `word1|word2||||word3||word4|` , i tried `line.split("\\|");` but this will split just one pipe what's the regex that can handle my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `"\\|+"` to match multiple (1 or more) pipes.

```
line.split("\\|+");
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/DrBoGx)